# Receiving videos via wifi

Tags: wireless, communication

I'm working on a electrical board that should receive videos from a server via WIFI. The size of the video is around 100 MB..it will be stored afterwards into an SD card ...so my question is what WIFI module should i use for this type of data?

Comment: There are numerous wifi boards available for different popular microcomputer kit systems, for example for Arduino.  Please say what system you are using, or are you building from scratch (if the latter, why?)

Comment: well i'm building it from scratch that's why i'm confused on what type of modules that can support the reception of such big sized video..and it's an application that i should build for a client of mine...one other thing is it necessary for such application to use a micro controller with an embedded OS in it ..?

Comment: The module does not care, it only passes data *through*. Can you clarify your quetsion: are you asking if there is an embedded board with Wifi and an SD card interface that can handle this, or are you asking about the connection type that can support a given data-rate to allow the data to transfer fast enough?

Comment: Also, without clarification, no you don't need an OS.

Comment: I will design the entire board with the SD card in it and the wifi module so i'm not looking for an already existing board ...but regarding the size of file that i should receive i was looking for suggestions about what's the best WIFI MODULE that fits in my application ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file size won't matter per se, it's the performance you require that will lead your design decision. A small microcontroller solution, such as an Arduino / AVR has SD Card and FAT libraries available and any compatible WiFi module will do the job. However you are only likely to get about a few MB/s at best through such a system, so your file may take a minute or two at best to transfer.

For higher performance probably the best choice is to use a Linux based ARM system that will probably have a dedicated SD and USB controllers with DMA and a clock speed more like 400MHz. You also get the benefit of very robust host drivers and would be able to use a mass produced WiFi dongle (or equivalent chipset) rather than something with an embedded TCP stack.

Really whichever way you go the likely easiest / best solution for a custom design is to look around at reference designs or open source projects and do what they do. As an added bonus you can also check reliability and performance of the combination before committing to your own design.